# How shall I exit search box in Evince?

Tags: evince

In Evince 42.3, after I search something in the search box in the top part of the evince window, I can't exit the search box, so that the left panel used for displaying search results can return back to showing the outlines of the pdf file. How can I exit it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: When you type a search string, a sort of left-pointing arrow with an `x`in it appears to the right. Click that. It will empty the search bar and remove the search results.

Comment: It empties the search bar, and search results in the left panel, but doesn't remove the bar, and return the left panel to outlines

Comment: Simply press "Esc"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the mouse, click the *Find a word of phrase* icon (the one that looks like a magnifying glass to the right of the *Zoom* dropdown) in the top bar. To start a search, you also click that icon.

When using the keyboard, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit search. With the keyboard, you enter search with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.